# How to manage url routing in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I’m working on url routing

1. I want to redirect page without change url.

When type url www.example.com/Default.aspx that time url show as same but return page Home/Index (Controller/Action)

2. I want to redirect page with actual url.

And second require is when type www.example.com/Default.aspx that time show url in address bar Home/Index and return this page

How to possible please describe in details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cleanest way of doing this is to use the URL Rewrite module in IIS. However, as you asked about doing it in MVC I'll cover that first:

To achieve 1 (when /default.aspx is requested return /home/index.
Add the following to your route table:

```
routes.MapRoute("HomepageDefault", "default.aspx", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

To achieve 2, you need to redirect the request - easiest way to do this will be to set a route up to an actionresult, and then redirect it:

```
routes.MapRoute("RedirectRoute", "default.aspx", new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirect" });
```

And then in the ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

The alternative is to do this with the [URL Rewrite Module in IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

To achieve 1:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite rule">
          <match url="^default.aspx$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/home/index" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

To achieve 2:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
       <rule name="redirect">
         <match url="^default.aspx$" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="/home/index" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```